# Generating a custom excel file from an excel file template

Tags: java, apache-poi

Now, I'm trying to generate an excel file from my template. My case is like this:
I have one original excel template file and I should generate several custom excel files depending on the retrieved data.
Is there any easy good workflow to follow.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? What data do you want to fetch and from where? What should be the output? You can maybe mention also something about formats of input/output excels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution, before giving a question, I had tried to find out a solution to it and I could not manage how to do it. And one idea come into my mind, it was so straightforward :).
So my code is like this:

```
 final String originalExcel = "D:\\work\\excel\\original.xls";
 String pathname = "D:\\work\\excel\\generated\\custom1.xls";
 File original = new File(originalExcel);
 File file = new File(pathname);
 FileUtils.copyFile(original, file);//I copied from my template before before changing it
 FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);
 final HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(stream);
 final HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(1); // so, here I can change my custom excel file.
```